# Efficient search algorithm for files with specifed extension C/C++

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, search, filesystems

I want to implement faster directory search.
Is there any algorithm in c/c++ is available for that ?

Comment: This depends on the platform's file system.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "directory search"? Things are mostly I/O bound here. Why do you want this faster search, what do you currently have that is too slow? What is the bottleneck in that solution?

Comment: it should not overload CPU and with optimal memory utilization.

Comment: I really doubt a directory search would overload CPU.

Comment: directory search =>e.g. search *.txt files recursively in some dir. Anyone knows linux find command  is implemented ?

Comment: This is an excellent question

Comment: Why don't you google for that? I am sure that you will find articles on how `find` is implemented (or `rgrep`, `grep -r` if what you want is search *in* the .txt files) and you can always look at the code

Comment: Your question remains unclear. Do you mean to reproduce the functionality of `find . -name '*.txt' -print` or of `find . -name '*.txt' -print | xargs grep FOO` ?

Comment: The bottleneck in a directory search is typically the IO interaction.  If it's CPU bound, you're definitely doing it wrong, and should show some code so we could help with that aspect.  Directory traversal is not going to be faster than your IO device can serve.

Answer (score 4):

Check boost::filesystem library on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm, there you have a recursive_directory_iterator class.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a C++ thing per se, but usually directory search is slow because of IO, and because you must stat each file (or whatever the OS equivalent is non-unix systems) to find out anything besides its name.  One way to make this faster would be to keep write a server that keeps the inodes and filenames in memory. Of course the difficulty is that the inode information is not static.  You would need to listen to file system changes to keep your cache up to date.  That is definitely possible in linux, but I have no experience with it on other systems. As you can see, another theme of this problem is that it is very system and possibly filesystem dependent.  Maybe a system-independent library like Boost::Filesystem can help, but I doubt it implements directory update callbacks.

Maybe just install Google Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a windows solution (http://ideone.com/5dFVf)

```
class file_iterator : std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, const WIN32_FIND_DATA> {
    HANDLE handle;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fdata;
public:
    file_iterator() :handle(NULL) { 
#ifdef _DEBUG
        memset(&fdata, 0, sizeof(fdata); 
#endif //_DEBUG
    }
    file_iterator(const std::wstring& path) :handle(FindFirstFile(path.c_str(), &fdata)) {}
    file_iterator(file_iterator&& b) :handle(b.handle) {b.handle = NULL;}
    file_iterator& operator=(file_iterator&& b) {close(); handle = b.handle; b.handle = NULL;}

    void close() {
        if (handle) 
            FindClose(handle); 
#ifdef _DEBUG
        memset(&fdata, 0, sizeof(fdata); 
#endif //_DEBUG
    }

    const WIN32_FIND_DATA& operator*() {return fdata;}
    file_iterator& operator++() {if (FindNextFile(handle , &fdata)==false) close(); return *this;}
    bool operator==(const file_iterator& b) {return handle == b.handle;}
    bool operator!=(const file_iterator& b) {return handle != b.handle;}
};

std::vector<std::wstring> 
    find_files_with_extension(
        const std::wstring& folder, 
        const std::wstring& extension, 
        std::vector<std::wstring>* result=NULL) 
{
    std::wstring filepath = folder + L"/*";
    std::vector<std::wstring> local_result;
    std::deque<std::wstring> todo;
    if (result == NULL) 
        result = &local_result;
    file_iterator iter(filepath);
    while(iter != file_iterator()) {
       std::wstring folder_file((*iter).cFileName);
       if ((*iter).dwFileAttributes | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
           todo.push_back(folder_file);
       else if (folder_file.size() > extension.size() && folder_file.substr(folder_file.size()-extension.size())==extension)
           result->push_back(folder_file);
       ++iter;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<todo.size(); ++i)
        find_files_with_extension(todo[i], extension, result);
    return *result;
}
```

This uses a breadth-first search, which takes a little more RAM and is slightly more complicated, but faster due to caching.

Answer (score 0):

Searching is an OS feature these days, and those who are trying to implement third party indexing are giving up.  Even Google Desktop is not being updated and most consider it dead:

https://superuser.com/questions/194082/is-google-desktop-search-a-dead-project

If you install a search server on someone's computer and get caught hogging disk and CPU--and you do not have a *very, VERY* good reason for doing so--you will not only waste a lot of time writing code and patching bugs but you will also alienate your users.

For most cross-platform apps, letting the users find the files in the Explorer/Finder/Nautilus and then making your app accept multi-file drag and drops is a better answer.  Also, most "common dialogs" for opening files provide built in search functionality now.

If you're trying to write a search-accelerated tool for a specific platform, hook into that platform's API, which may even permit you to supplement its index.  Here's Microsoft's Programmatic Search API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266517(v=vs.85).aspx

OS/X has the spotlight API:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/SpotlightQuery.html

I'm not quite sure if there's "canon" for search in the Linux world, but most all of the relevant versions of Ubuntu now ship with Tracker:

http://live.gnome.org/Tracker/Documentation